# Rails 5 reads environment variables as string in YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails 5 app and I am trying to import my Environment Variables in a yaml file, which I can then import in the `environment.rb`. My `config/aws.yml` looks as follows:

```
S3_BUCKET: <%= ENV["S3_BUCKET"] %>
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
```

Then in my `environment.rb` I have the following:

```
require_relative 'application'
aws_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'aws.yml')
if File.exist?(aws_file)
  YAML.safe_load(File.open(aws_file)).each do |k, v|
    ENV[k.to_s] = v
  end
end
```

on running my `rails c` this is what I get:

```
[1] pry(main)> ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET')
=> "<%= ENV[\"S3_BUCKET\"] %>"
```

How can I pass the actual environment variable rather than it pulling the name of the environment variable as a string?

EDIT: Adding more relevant information

My credentials are stored in my `elastic-beanstalk` configuration and I am trying to load the values from the configuration to my `yaml` file.

Comment: It seems very curious that your `yml` file is using `erb` syntax. It also seems very curious that you are attempting to load `ENV` variables by referencing `ENV` variables. I would think that your `values` in your `yml` file would be the actual values you want to load into your `ENV` variables.

Comment: @jvillian Those values are in my `elasticbeanstalk` configuration and I am trying to load them in the `yaml` file from over there

Comment: You should probably state that in your question. I don't use `elasticbeanstalk`. But, if the `config` file is also a `yml` file, then it seems like you would want to load that and then set your `ENV` vars based on the content thereof.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. I don't see anything in your code about elastic-beanstalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= ... %>` is a feature of ERB, not YAML. You'd need to first run your YAML file through ERB to cause the `<%= ... %>` to execute and then load it as YAML.

But there's a deeper problem. Your YAML file is trying to get its values from environment variables. But then you set those same environment variables from the YAML values. It's circular.

Instead use something like [Encrypted Credentials](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2) introduced in Rails 5.2 to manage your secrets. Then write `config/initializer/aws.rb` to set the necessary environment variables from those secrets. This is nice because it stores your secrets in your app rather than in the deployment platform. Then it can be run with full secrets anywhere.

Or you can set the environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk via the "Environment Properties" console.

Comment: I am not on Rails 5.2 yet. I am using Rails 5.0

Comment: My credentials are stored in the `elasticbeanstalk` configuration

Comment: Consider upgrading. Encrypted Credentials lets you move your credentials out of the deployment platform and into the app. Then you don't need glue code like you're trying to write.

Comment: @anonn023432 Your other option is to set the environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk. That would be "Environment Properties".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you have already, add this to `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.x.aws = config_for(:aws)
```

And you'll be able to access it:

```rb
Rails.configuration.x.aws.S3_BUCKET # => ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `fetch`, it worked on my case:

```
S3_BUCKET: <%= ENV.fetch("S3_BUCKET") %>
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <%= ENV.fetch("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") %>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <%= ENV.fetch("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") %>
```